# Rails Settings in test leak over to development

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using the [rails-settings-cached](https://github.com/huacnlee/rails-settings-cached) gem in my rails 4 app. But when I change something in my tests, e.g. Setting['style.promotions'] = 4, this value changes also in the dev environment. How is that even possible?